# Matlab: How to count?

Tags: matlab

I have above image with white background. I need to count the circles and get diameter of each circle using morphological, logical and set operations of matlab. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: It's been a while since I used Matlab's image processing toolbox so the best idea I've got right now is to break out the documentation.  I'm not going to do it for you, are you going to do it for yourself ?

Comment: Do a google search for "matlab image processing circle fitting"...you'll get all sorts of useful tutorials.

Also: counting the number of [connected components](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html) will give you the number of circles.

Comment: Morphology requires that you know what the structuring element is before hand, before you apply any morphological operations.  The only way that I can see you using morphology is to use circular structuring elements and iterate over a set of radii and perform an erosion for each radii.  When you find a single isolated pixel as the output for a given radius in your set, this is most likely the radius of that particular circle centered at this point.  This is tedious as you don't know what radii to start with.   Whoever asked you to find the diameters using morphology is absolutely whacked.

Comment: On another note, why don't you use [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) and calculate the bounding box? Assuming that the circles are actually circles (i.e. the major and minor axes have equal lengths), the width / height of the bounding box will be your diameter.

Comment: @rayryeng - actually this clearly from the same class makes it look like a reasonable homework question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678240

Comment: @nkjt - Hah!  I knew that question looked similar.  The only thing that is missing is the fact that the diameters of the coins / circles are known.  Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html):

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJidJ.png');
bw = img(:,:,1) < 128; %// convert to logical mask
d = regionprops( bw, 'EquivDiameter' );
d = [d.EquivDiameter]; %// array with diameter of each coin.
```